# How to find the the number of distinct values of function for a given value of z?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

How many distinct values can the following function take at a given value of z ?
$$f(z)=\sqrt{\frac{z^2-1}{\sqrt{z}}}(z-i)^{1/3}$$

The answer is given to be 12.

My method (kind of vague):
At first I tried to remove the square roots and cube roots on the right hand side by squaring two times and cubing one time, which results in:
$$[f(z)]^{12}=\frac{(z^2-1)^6}{z^3}(z-i)^{4}$$
I don't know any theorem, then I just concluded that if the f(z) has power equal to 12 than it will have 12 distinct roots. I think it is just a coincidence. I tried to google it, which increased my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another was to analyze the exercise is this:

For a given $z$, there are two values of $\sqrt{z}$, and thus two values of $\dfrac{z^2-1}{\sqrt{z}}$.

For each of those two values there are two values of $\sqrt{\dfrac{z^2-1}{\sqrt{z}}}$, so four altogether.

Then there are three values of $(z-i)^{1/3}$ making a total of $4\times3=12$ possible values.

Comment: Will all these values be inherently distinct?

Comment: @harshitsingh That is an appropriate consideration. But the fact that the roots of orders $2$ and $3$ are relatively prime leads me to doubt it in this case.

Comment: Can you add some references so that I can dive deeper into this? I'm a Physics student. Can you mention the theorems  used here , that would really help.

Comment: @harshitsingh You can search the web for "roots of complex numbers" to find many sources.

Comment: Thank you @John :)